# New Test Run using REST API - ALM 14

Tags: java, rest, testing, automation, alm

I am trying to update the test results using REST API for ALM Saas
http://targetserver:targetport/qcbin/rest/domains/ALMDomain/projects/ALMProject/runs - EndPoint

Below are the body(payload):

```
<Entity Type='run'>
 <Fields>
 <Field Name='name'><Value>testnamegoeshere</Value></Field>
 <Field Name='test-instance'><Value>1</Value></Field>
  <Field Name='cycle-id'><Value>cycleidgoeshere</Value></Field>
 <Field Name='test-id'><Value>testidgoeshere</Value></Field>
 <Field Name='subtype-id'><Value>hp.qc.run.MANUAL</Value></Field>
 <Field Name='status'><Value>Failed</Value></Field>
 <Field Name='owner'><Value>testownergoeshere</Value></Field> 
 </Fields>
</Entity>
```

Getting response is like this.
false
here is my question: I need to know if am passing correct parameter or not and please let me know, is API got changed or anything else??

Answer (score 0):

URL you mentioned is for creating a new run. You have mentioned that you are going to update the test run. For that you need to append **/{id} (id of run)**. Make sure you are making put call and not post for this operation.

Also probably you wont require to give cycle-id, test-id, test-instance details with update because those are now constants. If you are creating new run then it is mandatory. 
Hope this helps you to solve.